# Hard deleted object still appears in AppEngine admin console

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Objectify on GAE for Java. Recently Had a situation where I deleted object using ofy( ).delete() which is supposed hard delete an object off the datastore.

However I was able to still see this hard-deleted object in AppEngine's admin console (datastore viewer). When I try to expand (edit) this object by clicking on the ID/Name column I get an error "This entity doesn't exist." I can still retrieve this object from the datastore using ofy().get().

Is this because indexes aren't updated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the eventually-consistent nature of queries in the high-replication datastore.

Here is a good place to start reading:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: So the only way to make sure to not see the entity, is to delete it in transaction? Then If I run get() on that entity even outside of transaction I can still see the value, right?

Comment: Get-by-key has strong consistency whether you are in a transaction or not - although the only way you can guarantee the state of the datastore is by using a transaction.  With Objectify you can use `Query.hybrid(true)` which will turn your query into a keys-only query + batch get.  Ofy will automatically remove entries which show up in the query results but don't actually exist.

Comment: Well, thanks. Regarding eventual consistency - if I make put() - eventualy consistent and then inside transaction I call get() on the same key - am I guaranteed to get what I put (I can guarantee no other writes happened with this entity)? I think theoretically not. Is there any practical bounds (time bounds) that can give me some guarantees (percentage)?

Comment: I suppose the Query.hybrid(true) throws an error when it can not transform to 'query by key query'. Note aside(but related to the topic): the defaults of objectify are documented in ObjectifyService.factory().begin().

Comment: In the default mode Objectify is in STRONG consistency mode, meaning that any reads (Query or ofy.load().id()) are reading the last value, right? In EVENTUAL consistency mode, I suppose ofy.load().id() reads the last value, cause it creates a key internally.

Comment: All of this is spelled out in detail in the Google documentation, which is pretty much required reading. In short: Queries are always weakly consistent, get-by-key is strongly consistent unless you explicitly make it EVENTUAL. Put/save operations are either async or sync; it doesn't quite make sense to talk about consistency there. Please read through Google's datastore docs.

Comment: Well, I would not mix sync or async into this topic. I think it has few to do with it. All my questions are related to this option: DatastoreServiceConfig config = withReadPolicy(new ReadPolicy(Consistency.EVENTUAL)). I think you misundestood my questions. But thats ok, I have to search answeers elswere:- Sincirely, Thanks for your enormous effort!

Comment: Read policy does not affect writes in any way.